# Say, send_message and send, do not work in @bot event what to do? discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Hello reread all the documentation on discord.py, and unfortunately did not find a simple thing like the *on_member_join* event in the chat send a message?

I use a non-standard construction, and such a construction client = discord.Client (), but as I understood a new *bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')*

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(bot.user.name)
    print(bot.user.id)
    print('------')

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   print(member.name)   
   bot.send(member.name);
```

Print () output to the console properly, but to send it to the chat of the discord unfortunately does not work(

I also tried:

1. bot.say(member.name);
2. bot.send_message(member.name)
3. bot.send(member.name)

But all the time an error is issued "'Bot' object has no attribute 'say'"

Please tell me what is wrong I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of `discord.py` you're using will change how you send messages.

`discord.py` 0.16, the "async" branch, is the current stable release.  It has two ways of sending messages. (In the below, note that `Bot` is a subclass of `Client`, so every `Bot` also has access to all of the `Client` methods)

1. Using [`Client.send_message(target, message)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.send_message).  This is what you
   would    use in `on_message(message)`

   ```
   await bot.send_message(message.channel, "I am responding to your message")
   ```
2. Using `Bot.say(message)`.  This is an easy way of sending
       messages    back to the channel a command was invoked in.  [It *only*
       works in commands.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#can-i-use-bot-say-in-other-places-aside-from-commands)

   ```
   await bot.say("I am responding to your command")
   ```

`discord.py` 1.0, the "rewrite" branch, is the most recent branch.  It's considered experimental still, but is entirely usable. [One of the many changes is the way that message sending works.](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/migrating.html#sending-messages)

Now, instead of having methods on the client to send messages, we have methods on the things that receive messages to send them a message.  These all implement the [`Messageable`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable) abstract base class, and have a [`send`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.abc.Messageable.send) method.  In your `on_message`, this would look like

```
await message.channel.send("I am responding to your message")
```

I believe you are using version 1.0

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response, I tried to send a message not from event on_message. And from event on_member_join I solved this problem, it turned out that the installation discrod.py half of the libraries, including send_message (), were not installed. It was decided that I made virtualenv and updated all the packages. 

Your answer helped me with the bot.say() because it is a very long time came an error about the "ctx" - which was the example, thank you very much again!